# exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException' even when route is presennt in route:list

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-8

I'm getting following error

`exception 'Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException'`

I have tried following commands

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

Used route is listed in route:list. still getting error

Route is as follows

`Route::post('roles/{role}/update-permissions', 'PermissionController@assignPermissions')->name('role.update-Permissions');`

List is showing
`api/v1/admin/roles/{role}/update-permissions                                            | role.update-Permissions                 | App\Modules\User\Http\Controllers\PermissionController@assignPermissions`

I'm calling this url
api/v1/admin/roles/1/update-permissions

Comment: What is the generated route that you're trying to access?

Comment: What url are you calling? what does php artisan route:list show for that route

Comment: Check `role` exists in the database and doesn't have been soft deleted.

Comment: updated url in question

Comment: yes role exists in database

Comment: check out where the "admin" is inserted into you url.... **api/v1/admin/roles/1/update-permissions** but your **Route::post('roles/{role}/update-permissions')** do not have admin

Comment: @Doro Considering it's showing in `routes:list`, I'm going to guess that the route is defined inside of a Route::group with prefix.

Comment: Can you show `assignPermissions`?

Comment: `ModelNotFoundException` will get changed to a `NotFoundHttpException` before the handler renders the exceptions ... so its possible there is a `ModelNotFoundException` being thrown

Comment: ```php artisan vendor:publish```

Comment: Tried php artisan vendor:publish no change... @aynber for now it just have dd()